# How to get position() in sequence after ignoring NULL values in xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am facing issue while displaying the position in html using xslt when xml nodes contain null value. The portion of xml is below. The expected output is:

```
    1: 45
    2: abc
    3: 1

    <a>45</a>
    <a>null</a>
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>null</a>
    <a>null</a>
    <a>1</a>

    Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, but **complete** example, including a **well-formed input** and the expected output **as code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

```
<root>
    <a>45</a>
    <a>null</a>
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>null</a>
    <a>null</a>
    <a>1</a>
</root>
```

you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="a[not(.='null')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ': ', .)" />
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

to produce:

```
1: 45<br/>2: abc<br/>3: 1<br/>
```

which in HTML would render as:

```
1: 45
2: abc
3: 1
```